# C++ AVL to array in order traversal

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am trying to copy the keys of an AVL tree to a pre allocated array using in-order traversal. 
This is my code:

```
void traverse(Node<int>* node, int* arr, int iteration) {
    if (node->leftSon) {
        traverse(node->leftSon, arr, iteration);
    }
    std::cout << "node->key = " << node->key << "   ";
    *(arr) = node->key;
    std::cout << "arr = " << *(arr) << "  "<<"iteration = "<<iteration<<"\n";
    arr++;
    iteration++;
    if (node->rightSon) {
        traverse(node->rightSon, arr,iteration);
    }
}
/*****************************************************/
int main() {
    Node<int> n1 = Node<int>(1);
    AVL<int> tree = AVL<int>(&n1);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(21);
    tree.insert(12);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(22);
    int size = tree.getSize() + 1;
    std::cout << "size = " << size << "  root = "<<tree.getRoot()->key << "\n";
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    traverse(tree.getRoot(), arr, 0);
    std::cout <<"\n**************printing array:*********\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
size = 6  root = 20
node->key = 1   arr = 1  iteration = 0
node->key = 2   arr = 2  iteration = 0
node->key = 12  arr = 12  iteration = 1
node->key = 20  arr = 20  iteration = 0
node->key = 21  arr = 21  iteration = 1
node->key = 22  arr = 22  iteration = 2

**************printing array:*********
20
21
22
0
0
0
```

**Problem:** I cannot understand this strange behavior, as in the `traverse` function, the value which got inserted to `arr` is correct and at the correct cell too, however i don't understand why in the `main` function i got that weird output?
Does the 2 recursive calls have an impact on this?

**NOTE:** The variable `iteration` doesn't play any key role at all, I simply used it for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Please don't add [Solved] in your question titles. It isn't helpful.

Comment: @talonmies, Thank you for the tip, i'll keep this in mind for later.

Answer (score 2):

... and in addition to the `iteration` parameter needing to be a pointer, you're also passing the `arr` parameter by value.

When you call `traverse()` recursively, the recursive invocation of `arr` has its own copy of the pointer. It goes ahead and increments, that's fine, but this has absolutely nothing to do with the `arr` parameter in the parent caller, which still has its own `arr` parameter. When the recursive call returns, the original traverse() picks up with the original value of the pointer.

I would suggest using a reference for `iteration` too, something like this:

```
void traverse(Node<int>* node, int* &arr, int &iteration)
```

... or some variation of. You'd have to invoke `traverse()` in a slightly different way, initially.

Then, each recursive invocation of traverse() will end up scribbling over the same pointer value, instead of its own copy.

Comment: you mean ` int** arr` (not ` int* &arr`)?

Comment: you're right about `iteration`. see the modification i did in my answering to my question. Sorry for the bother :)

Comment: I did mean int *&arr;  This would not actually result in any changes to traverse().

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i should declare `iteration` as a pointer to integer, and use it to update `arr`, i.e. `*(arr + *iteration) = value`
the updated code:

```
void traverse(Node<int>* node, int* arr, int* iteration) {
    if (node->leftSon) {
        traverse(node->leftSon, arr, iteration);
    }
    std::cout << "node->key = " << node->key << "   ";
    *(arr + *iteration) = node->key;
    std::cout << "arr = " << *(arr) << "  "<<"iteration = "<<*iteration<<"\n";

    *iteration +=1;
    if (node->rightSon) {
        traverse(node->rightSon, arr,iteration);
    }
}
/*****************************************************/
int main() {
    Node<int> n1 = Node<int>(1);
    AVL<int> tree = AVL<int>(&n1);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(21);
    tree.insert(12);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(22);
    int size = tree.getSize() + 1;
    std::cout << "size = " << size << "  root = "<<tree.getRoot()->key << "\n";
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int a = 0;
    traverse(tree.getRoot(), arr, &a);
    std::cout <<"\n**************printing array:*********\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << *(arr + i) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which yields the output:

```
size = 6  root = 20
node->key = 1   arr = 1  iteration = 0
node->key = 2   arr = 1  iteration = 1
node->key = 12  arr = 1  iteration = 2
node->key = 20  arr = 1  iteration = 3
node->key = 21  arr = 1  iteration = 4
node->key = 22  arr = 1  iteration = 5

**************printing array:*********
1
2
12
20
21
22
```

**However** the argument `arr` should still be `int*` and not `int**`